# Invoke standard Case Merge action via LWC

Tags: case, merge, navigationmixin.navigate

Would it be possible to invoke the standard Salesforce Case Merge action from LWC?

Having a new component like say action-form similar to existing record-form component would work well. for example:

```
<lightning-action-form
  input-variables={caseIds} 
  object-api-name="Case"
  action="MergeCase"
></lightning-record-form>
```

Is there currently any workarounds to open in new tab, something like using NavigationMixin like below or a URL hack:

```
navigateToCaseMassMergePage() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            ids: '5005r00000CERVDAA1,5005r00000CERVDAA2',
            objectApiName: 'Case', 
            actionName: 'merge'
        }
    });
}
```

This would be used in ISV 2GP.

Ref: Merge Duplicate Cases in Lightning Experience

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cases_merge.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no url hack at the moment to invoke the Case Merge popup through a custom lwc. There is an idea here which can be upvoted:- [Access Merge Cases through a Custom Button or URL Parameters](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgQVUAZ/access-merge-cases-through-a-custom-button-or-url-parameters)

I found few git repos related to case merge which you can look into to build your own version of it in LWC, they are:-

1. https://github.com/stonarelli/CaseMerge
2. https://github.com/sankalpjhingran/CaseMerge
3. https://github.com/mambomerge/case-listview-using-flow-recipe